# Express server on Node shuts down when data can't be fetched from get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This app fetches the current weather when a user types in a city name, or it can get your current location and current weather using your IP address.

The problem: When a user types in a city that doesn't exist, like "jklsafbhjbdsfjhbf" a failure message fades in as expected, but then the server shuts down and the user can't make any more weather requests without restarting the server in the terminal.

I think the problem resides somewhere within my promises in the file **weather.js**, or possibly in the way I am handling my get requests on the front-end in **weatherFetcher.js** or on the back-end in **app.js**

Need help fixing this so the server doesn't shut down and the user can continue to make weather requests.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var weather = require('./public/js/weather.js');
var location = require('./public/js/location.js');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Express Server Started on port ' + PORT);
});
app.get('/location', function(req, res) {
    var city = req.query.city;
    weather(city).then(function (currentWeather) {
        res.json(currentWeather);
    });
});
app.get('/guessweather', function(req, res) {
    location().then(function (guessedLocation) {
        weather(guessedLocation).then(function (guessedWeather) {
            res.json(guessedWeather);
        });
    });
});
```

**weather.js**

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function (location) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);
        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + encodedLocation + '&units=imperial&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0';
        if (!location) {
            return reject('No location provided');
        }
        request({url: url, json: true}, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                return reject('Unable to fetch weather.');
            } else {
                return resolve('The current temperature in ' + body.name + ' is ' + body.main.temp + ' degrees farenheit with humidity at ' + body.main.humidity + '%.');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**location.js**

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var url = 'http://ipinfo.io';
        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                return reject('Unable to fetch location.');
            } else {
                console.log(body.city);
                return resolve(body.city);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**weatherFetcher.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#success').hide();
    $('#failure').hide();
    $('#noCity').hide();
    $('#findMyWeather').click(function(event) {
        $('#success').hide();
        $('#failure').hide();
        $('#noCity').hide();
        var $cityName = $('#city').val();
        if (typeof $cityName === 'string' && $cityName.length > 0) {
            $.get('/location?city=' + $cityName, function (data) {
            }).done(function (data) {
                $("#success").html(data).fadeIn();
                $("#success").prepend('<p id="cityTitle" class="lead">'+ $cityName +'</p>');
                $('#city').value = ""; //This doesn't seem to be working
            }).fail(function () {
                $("#failure").fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            $("#noCity").fadeIn();
        }
    });
    $('#findLocalWeather').click(function(event) {
        $('#success').hide();
        $('#failure').hide();
        $('#noCity').hide();
        $.get('/guessweather', function (data) {
            if (data == "") {
                $("#failure").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $("#success").html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Weather Scraper</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

 <!--jQuery & Bootstrap-->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <!--javascript-->
 <script src="./js/weatherFetcher.js"></script>

 <!--CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/weatherStyles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="heading" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 center">
                <div id="pageIntro">
                    <h1 class="middle">Current Weather</h1>
                    <p class="lead center marginTop">Enter a city to get the current weather or click Local Weather</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control marginTop" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Eg. London, Venice, Atlanta, Ho Chi Minh City...">
                </div>
                <button id="findMyWeather" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg marginTop">Get Weather by City</button>
                <button id="findLocalWeather" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg marginTop">Get Your Local Weather</button>
                <div id="alerts">
                    <div id="success" class="alert alert-info marginTop"></div>
                    <div id="failure" class="alert alert-danger marginTop">Could not find weather data for that city. Please try again.</div>
                    <div id="noCity" class="alert alert-danger marginTop">Please enter a city</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add error callback for rejected promise

```
 app.get('/location', function(req, res) {
        var city = req.query.city;
        weather(city).then(function (currentWeather) {  
            res.json(currentWeather);
        }, function (error) {
            res.json(404,error);
        });
    });
```

And in weather.js

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function (location) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);
    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + encodedLocation + '&units=imperial&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0';
    if (!location) {
      return reject('No location provided');
    }
    request({url: url, json: true}, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        return reject('Unable to fetch weather.');
      }
      if(body.main){
        return resolve('The current temperature in ' + body.name + ' is ' + body.main.temp + ' degrees farenheit with humidity at ' + body.main.humidity + '%.');
      }
      return reject(body.message)
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I added this error callback, but the server still shuts down and throws this message on the console. 

/Users/marcushurney/Desktop/node-course/Weather-App/public/js/weather.js:25
    return resolve('The current temperature in ' + body.name + ' is ' + body.main.temp + ' degrees farenheit with humidity at ' + body.main.humidity + '%.');
                                                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Comment: Can you post result of console.log(body)?

Comment: { coord: { lon: -84.39, lat: 33.75 },
  weather: 
   [ { id: 800,
       main: 'Clear',
       description: 'sky is clear',
       icon: '01d' } ],
  base: 'stations',
  main: 
   { temp: 24.03,
     pressure: 1031,
     humidity: 73,
     temp_min: 19.99,
     temp_max: 28.4 },
  visibility: 16093,
  wind: { speed: 3.24, deg: 30 },
  clouds: { all: 1 },
  dt: 1451999483,
  sys: 
   { type: 1,
     id: 760,
     message: 0.0086,
     country: 'US',
     sunrise: 1451997779,
     sunset: 1452033799 },
  id: 4180439,
  name: 'Atlanta',
  cod: 200 }

Comment: ^ That was if I enter a valid city name and get a result. If I enter a city that doesn't exist, then this is the body: { cod: '404', message: 'Error: Not found city' } and the error as follows:
/Users/marcushurney/Desktop/node-course/Weather-App/public/js/weather.js:27
    return resolve('The current temperature in ' + body.name + ' is ' + body.main.temp + ' degrees farenheit with humidity at ' + body.main.humidity + '%.'); TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined